# Close Boostrap Modal on Contact Form 7 submit

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal, contact-form-7

In a Bootstrap Modal, I have a Contact Form 7.
I can not make the Modal is closed after sending the mail.
What you do is go to the link of the "action" attribute of the form.
I can not delete the "action" attribute that is created dynamically.
Perhaps a solution might be to use "event.preventDefault ()" with "on_sent_ok".
But not how.

[Working Example](http://saviacomunicacion.com.ar/test2014/#sala-de-prensa)

Click in one note, then in **Compartir** , and then in de **Mail icon**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution with this code. When form submit, the Modal closes after 1 second.

```
j(".form-horizontal").live("submit", function(){
        j.post(this.action, j(this).serialize(), function(){
            //this callback is executed upon success full form submission close modal here

        }, "script");
     //this is to wait 1 second until close
        setTimeout(function() {j('.modal').modal('hide');}, 1000);          
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: How did you successfully insert a Contact Form 7 form in to a modal in the first place? I want to place a contact button, triggering a contact form modal, in my WordPress theme header. And then, like you, I want to close the form upon submission. I am getting confused, though.

Comment: In the theme footer, or where you place the code for the modal, I put the shortcode inside. I use Contact Form 7. When the modal shows, the form is inside.

Comment: Ah yes, I figured that out, using do_shortcode. Did you put this code in the Advanced Settings of the Contact Form 7 settings?

Comment: Look at the answer I put.

Answer (score 3):

- Paste this code in your functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'submit_cf7' );
function submit_cf7() {
    ?>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
            if ( event.detail.contactFormId == '36' ) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    jQuery('#contactModal').modal('hide');
                }, 2000);
            }
        }, false );
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

where 36 - your form ID. The modal window will close after 2 seconds

Answer (score 1):

No, i put the code in the modal. Just `<?php echo do_shortcode( '[the contact form 7 shortcode]' ); ?>` in the modal body.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <?php echo do_shortcode( '[the contact form 7 shortcode]' ); ?>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution, also i have bootstrap button on submit button click event.

```
on_sent_ok: "setTimeout("$('button.submit').prop('disabled', null).button('reset'); $('.modal').modal('hide');", 3000); 
ga('send', 'event', 'Купить быстро', 'Submit');"
```

This code should be placed in additional settings tab on edit contact form page